# C++ equivalent library for this python code for screenshots

Tags: library, python, c++, cross-platform

I want to capture screenshots of the whole screen and send them using tcp sockets. In python this can be done using PIL

```
from PIL import Image
im = grab()
im.save(filename)
```

It is cross-platform and the size of resulting images is mostly less than 500KB. I can't use python because the user may not have python installed and the screenshot utility is a part of a bigger program written is C++ which also handles the networking part. Is it possible to get all these features of the above given code using some C++ library or somehow use the python code as a library for C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excellent [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) library as well as providing a full GUI toolkit chain allows you to take screenshots as covered in [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800915/save-wxwidgets-window-screenshot).

wxWidgets is open source, free to use for commercial use and has been running since 1992 but is still under active development.

Answer (score 0):

The easy was is to embed python, (and the PIL/Pillow libraries), in your C++ application as described in the [documents](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) and shown in the demo `Demo/embed/`of the source distribution.

Note that you might also wish to do the networking side from Python as the built in libraries make this so much easier than C++ does.